# What does C-u mean in sequence "C-u M-x"

Tags: prefix-argument

I learnt that `C-u` default is to repeat 4 times.

For example:
<kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> is input tttt

However, when I type  <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>M-x</kbd>, it prompts a function list

[image]

What does invoking `C-u` mean here?

Comment: It's the "prefix argument", an interactive function (a.k.a. command, something that you usually run by pressing `M-x`) can use this argument to change its behavior. It is useful for commands that would normally be bound to some key and would not ask for your input interactively after being called. However, it is entirely within the purview of the author of the command how to interpret the argument. Often times its the number of repetitions of the command, but it could be something else entirely.

Comment: ty, could you please transmit the comment to answer. @wvxvw

Comment: Presumably, you must have some package installed that alters the behaviour of `M-x`. Normally, `M-x` runs the command `execute-extended-command`, which does nothing but run the named command. If you give it a prefix with  `C-u`, that information is merely passed to the executed command. `execute-extended-command` itself doesn't do anything else with it.

Comment: ty, very clear. @HaraldHanche-Olsen

Comment: so C-x is internal command, M-x is extended command? @HaraldHanche-Olsen

Comment: `C-x` is merely a prefix key. It does not run any command, unless followed by at least one more keystroke. As to “extended”: I find the terminology a bit odd. The thing is that `M-x` lets you run any command by naming the corresponding emacs function. If the command is not bound to any key (really, key *sequence*), that is the only way you can run it. Example: `C-x C-f` is bound to the command `find-file`. So you can also run it by `M-x find-file RET` (where `RET` stands for the return key). The keybinding `C-x C-f` is just for convenience.